# How to separate forename and surnames in R?

Tags: r, parsing, text

I have a list of brazilian names and I need to separate forenames and last names. The problem is that many brazilians have only one forename but others have two forenames. Is there a way to separate these names that takes this particularity into account?

edit: most men have a surname with two words and women can have two (when single) or three words (when married). The dataframe identifies gender but not marital status. That said, I want to separate the components of the name into: first name, last two names, and last three names when `genderMale=0`.

Dataframe example:

```
fullName;                           genderMale;
Antonio Oliveira Souza              1
Carlos Antonio Oliveira Souza       1
Maria Oliveira Silva                0 
Maria Oliveira Souza Silva          0
Antonia Maria Oliveira Souza Silva  0
```

The dataframe must look like this:

```
  fullName;                          genderMale;  firstName;  lastTwoNames;     lastThreeNames;
  Antonio Oliveira Souza             1            Antonio     Oliveira Souza    NA
  Carlos Antonio Oliveira Souza      1            Carlos      Oliveira Souza    NA
  Maria Oliveira Silva               0            Maria       Oliveira Silva    Maria Oliveira Souza
  Maria Oliveira Souza Silva         0            Maria       Souza Silva       Oliveira Souza Silva
  Antonia Maria Oliveira Souza Silva 0            Antonia     Souza Silva       Oliveira Souza Silva
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a rule that enables us to determine where the forenames end and the last names start?  If not, then it's going to be tricky...

Comment: I'm afraid not. Brazilians basically know how to recognize forenames and surnames when they see it. The only rule I know of is the number of words in the surname: most men have a surname with two words and women can have two (when single) or three words (when married). The dataframe identifies gender but not marital status.

Answer (score 1):

A solution to your problem will come in two parts:

1. Separation of the full name into its component parts
2. Classification of each component to either "forename" or "lastname"

The first part is trivial and, as @MattKaye suggests, `tidyr::separate` is an obvious option.

The second part is [three-pipe problem](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/three-pipe_problem).  Your comment that "Brazilians basically know how to recognize forenames and surnames when they see it" confirms my suspicion that there's not going to be a one-line algorithmic solution that handles every case.  It's a classification problem.  And it's unlikely that any solution will be 100% accurate.

There may be some low hanging fruit to be picked.  For example,

- if the full name has two or more components, then the first element must be a first name and the last component a last name.  (Assuming no data errors.)
- if the full name has three components, then it's probably one forename followed by a two element last name
- are there perhaps names that are *always* a first name or *always* a last name?  Then we can classify that element (and every preceding/following element) as a first name/last name.

Classifiers aren't my area of expertise.  Do you have a large independent dataset you can use as training data?  If so, perhaps a neural network is a possibility.

The bottom line is that without a deterministic (set of) rule(s) to apply, you have your work cut out.  At the very least, you're going to have to give us more information if we are going to make even vaguely sensible suggestions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will update my question to make it simpler and maybe I can work something out.

Comment: @BenBolker: Yes, it should. Thank you. I will correct it.

Answer (score -1):

`separate` from `tidyr` does this. You'll need to use a regex to separate based on the second to last space (or some other rule, since my knowledge of Brazilian names is limited), but I'd look here: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html

Comment: I don't think this (yet) addresses @Limey's point, which is how to know where the separation should occur. Since `separate` operates either on a string (regex, such as `" "`) or as a fixed position (number, not easily predetermined), I think this alone might not be the best approach. Regardless, answers usually do better when they demonstrate resolution of the question.

Comment: Yeah, normally I'd agree but without more knowledge and context, I'm not sure I'd be able to come up with the rule or the regex to use. Barring this, might make sense to do a `mutate` or something with a couple of custom functions, but I'll wait on more info from @savioecon on that